# Windows. C#. XBox360 Controller prevent default Guide Button popup panel and show my own

Tags: slimdx, xbox360

I want to use XBox360 Controller in my app. I can get user input with SlimDx.dll. But I cant catch 'XboxButton' or 'GuideButton' pressed. I want catch it to prevent showing default panel (see screenshot) and show my own panel with my controls. Is it possible?

[image]